# Why is integer returnvalue of function not interpreted the same as that integer

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, yield

Why does this work?

```
def nextSquare():
    i = 1;

    # An Infinite loop to generate squares
    while True:
        yield i*i
        i += 1  # Next execution resumes
                # from this point

# Driver code to test above generator
# function
for num in nextSquare():
    if num > 100:
        break
    print(num)
```

But not this?

```
def nextSquare():
    i = 1;

    # An Infinite loop to generate squares
    while True:
        yield i*i
        i += 1  # Next execution resumes
                # from this point

# Driver code to test above generator
# function
for num in 1:
    if num > 100:
        break
    print(num)
```

An integer is returned each time nextsquare is run so what is the difference between the first time nextsquare returns in

```
for num in nextSquare():
```

and

```
for num in 1:
```

Comment: that is a very abstract question. Do you want a solution, or a python implementation and design tradeoffs discussion?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the "yield" keyword do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> An integer is returned each time nextsquare is run

Right, `nextSquare` should be "run" first. You call it like `nextSquare()`, it returns an iterable, then the `for` loop iterates over it, like this:

```
retval = nextSquare()
it = iter(retval)
num = next(it)
while True:
    # loop body
    try:
        num = next(it)
    except StopIteration:
        break
```

However, it doesn't make sense to call `next(1)`, as it doesn't make sense to iterate over one single number - loops iterate over *collections* or something that is "collection-like". A single number certainly isn't anything like a collection, so you can't iterate over it.

The error message says exactly that:

```
>>> for _ in 1:
...  ...
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```